# Project runs in visual studio but fails in localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, malmo

I have loaded a template from Visual Studio for an ASP.NET MVC project. Of course, it runs fine and I can publish it to localhost. Great.

I then simplified it further (only two pages, only one controller, no databases). One action of the controller creates and instantiates a variable from [Project Malmo](https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo). This line:

```
AgentHost agentHost = new AgentHost();
```

Everything runs fine in Visual Studio, but the website breaks (only in localhost!) when that action is triggered:

> SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.

I feared it might be lack of read/write privileges, so I was generous with them, but I could not solve the problem that way. I have almost no experience at all with web programming, so I could really use some help here.

I [uploaded to Github](https://github.com/pablogps/MiniMalmo) a super basic project that replicates this problem.

**Update**:
I found a Microsoft consultant to help me with this problem, and we made some progress. It seems (but he was unsure and puzzled overall) like the core of the problem is some conflict between Visual Studio and localhost regarding Project Malmo dependencies. We made the localhost version work after fiddling and removing/installing dependencies, but then the website stopped working from Visual Studio!

A similar approach allowed me to recover functionallity from Visual Studio, and I have not tried localhost again. I will only try to publish the project in a different machine, to avoid conflicts (and also because that is what I ultimately need to do). This is not a good answer to my question (which is why I write it as an update) but it was good enough to let me resume my work.